# Cannot ping directly connected computers

Tags: debian, networking, ping

I want to at first apologize for how simple my question is. I am extremely new to networking and extremely new to Linux, so I am sorry if this question is elementary.

I am currently troublshooting pinging an IP address from two computers that are directly connected. I had them on a managed switch and it wasn't working and now I literally have them directly connected to one another and I cannot get them to ping each other.

I am running Debian 10 on one machine. The other machine is the Windows 10 command prompt.

Here is my networking interfaces file on Debian:

```
auto ens4f0np0
iface ens40np0 inet static
       address 10.15.0.2
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       gateway 10.15.0.1
       dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1
```

Here is the output for the Win10 `ipconfig`:

Windows IP Configuration

```
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Default Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::69d7:9819:edbe:421b%25
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.17.244.17
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::41f4:a1e5:c0db:2d28%6
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.45.40
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.17.0.1
```

Is there any reason why I would not get a response when I try to ping 10.15.0.2 on a directly connected computer?

-I have tried getting rid of the gateway because I read it wasn't needed.

-The NIC is Enabled in the BIOS, because I was able to download software over the internet when I connected it to a router for the download. So the NIC works.

-I have tried netmask 255.255.254.0 and that did not work. Maybe I have no understanding of how netmasks work and how it effects pinging locally? Probably.

-I have disabled the firewall by downloading the ufw tool and running `sudo ufw disable`

-I have had a DHCP server dynamically hand both of them IP addresses when they were both plugged into a managed switch and they could ping each other then. So there's something that I'm missing in the manual network config file.

Long Term Goal:
I am trying to create a computer imaging/ghosting station. I have successfully done this in the past using Debian, but I am trying to set up a new one and I have narrowed the issues I'm having down to the NIC not recieving ping requests when my computer is directly connected to it.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: That is one config file but two systems are involved. Add the other configuration to your question. Even better than the config file: Add the outputs of `ip a`, `ip r`, and `iptables -nvL` for both systems to your question.

Comment: Sorry, for the other computer I am running the Windows 10 command prompt. I'll add that.

Comment: On Windows it is the output of `ipconfig`

Comment: @HaukeLaging added it.

Comment: The Windows computer does not have a `10.15.0.0/24` address. This means the Windows and Debian computers are not on the same subnet, even if they are connected to the same wire.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I did not know that. So would changing my netmask in my linux config file to 255.255.0.0 allow them to see each other?

Comment: The computers should have the same netmask, and the network part of the addresses, i.e. the bitwise and of the netmask and the address, should be equal. If you don't have a DHCP server handing out addresses, you will have to assign a static address on the Windows machine, like you did on the Debian host.

Comment: This is what I was missing! Thank you!  I staticly set the IP and the netmask to be the same and it worked!